# IIS MVC 4.0 Where to find the Controller files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have developed a website which monitoring our wireless AP status. The site simply ping and return the result whether active or inactive.

Recently, i migrated the site to new machine by using the IIS export function. However, my windows password expired and i tried to change in IIS and it prompt for error. After some research, i notice that i did not export out the decryption key information from old machine. The only solution is to recreate the whole site.

I in the midst of creating the site. I try to find the controller file i created early in project folder located in IIS.

My question is, where did the controller file store? i search up and down still cannot find the files.

Anyone can advise where should i look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controllers will be compiled to a DLL in the bin directory of the website.  They are usually C# or vb.net files, that are not deployed as part of the application.

Comment: Hi Nathan,
Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to open up and see the code?

Comment: Yea, you can use something like [.net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [Telerik Decompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx?gclid=CJe34uvFn7kCFYdgpQodlHkA1A) to do the job for you